# Grade calculation in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I got a file name `txtGrade.txt` contain with this:

```
Name               Score
Nicki Minaj        60
```

I want to read and calculate every person in file by shell script and answer the grade like:

```
Name                Score         Grade
Nicki Minaj         60                C
```

The condition is `A>=80 , 79>=B>=70 ,69>=C>=60 , 59>=D>=50 , 49>=F`

Thank you for helping me 
Appreciate.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Kinda like that , helping me please.

Answer (score 0):

Commands you'll need:

- `tail -n +2` to print the second line onwards of a file.
- A [`case` statement](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Choices_.28case_and_select.29) **or** [arithmetic expressions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) to check which grade the score corresponds to.
- A loop to read the lines with names and scores:

  ```
  while read -r first_name last_name score
  do
      [here $first_name etc. can be used]
  done
  ```
- A [`case` statement](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Choices_.28case_and_select.29) to check which grade the score corresponds to.
- `printf '%s %s\n' 'some text' "$some_variable"` prints "some text" followed by a space, then the value of `$some_variable`, then a newline.

You'll also need some knowledge of [quoting/word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: What command to use the txtGrade.txt to calculate. Thank you so much

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I dont know how to pull the text file to use

Answer (score 0):

you can use Sed command to modify your file.
below is the code to modify the file with the grades and i am assuming that each column is separated by two tabs.

```
sed -i -e "1d" txtGrade.txt
file="ba.txt"

while IFS= read -r line
do
a=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
if [ $a -ge "80" ]
then
    sed -i -e "s/${line}/${line}\\t\\tA/g" txtGrade.txt
elif [ $a -ge "70" ] && [ $a -le "79" ]
then
    sed -i -e "s/${line}/${line}\\t\\tB/g" txtGrade.txt
elif [ $a -ge "60" ] && [ $a -le "69" ]
then
    sed -i -e "s/${line}/${line}\\t\\tC/g" txtGrade.txt
elif [ $a -ge "50" ] && [ $a -le "59" ]
then
    sed -i -e "s/${line}/${line}\\t\\tD/g" txtGrade.txt
elif [ $a -ge "49" ]
then
    sed -i -e "s/${line}/${line}\\t\\tF/g" txtGrade.txt
else 
    echo "Results are not correct"
    exit 1
fi
done <"$file"
sed -i "1 i\Name\t\tScore\t\tGrade" txtGrade.txt
```

If you like my answer please vote,
thanks

Comment: That's awesome man Thank you so much but what is the "ba.txt" how it comes.

Comment: ba.txt was the file which I used for running the script, I forget to replace that name with txtGrade.txt it will work and if you like the answer then please vote it.